# Project Tango SDK Kalman problems

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, kalman-filter, google-project-tango

I'm trying to follow along the instructions here:

https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/unity/unity-motion-tracking#troubleshooting

I've gotten this to work on earlier iterations.  However:

1) No longer a SampleContoller script.  What is the new protocol for camera control?

Comment: Please describe your problem, and add your current code with errors, etc. Do not rely on links, they may be added for further information, but not for the critical part of the post. See [ask].

Comment: Take a look at [tango-examples-unity](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity) repo, each project has its own PoseController script depending on the requirements.